# Broken Slick Slider

Tags: jquery, api, plugins, slick.js

I cannot figure out why my slider won't run. I had it working fine, then I tried to make it scroll vertically rather than horizontally and now it's broken, even though I've reset all the settings to standard.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="carousel">
<div><img src="images/slider/worlds.png" alt="" width="200" height="140"></div>
<div><img src="images/slider/gonz2.png" alt="" width="200" height="140"> </div>
</div>
<aside class="slider-frame"></aside>
```

I have the slick folder in my application tree and I have the CSS and JS linked. The CSS is in the head section like so:

```
/* Main Site Stylesheet */
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
/* Slick Stylesheet */
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
```

JS in the head section (I've tried putting this in the footer as well):

```
// jQuery
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
// Main Site JS
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ur-js.js"></script>
```

JS in the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Main JS File:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').slick({
  autoplay:true,
  autoplaySpeed:45,
  arrows:false,
  dots:false,
  infinite:true,
  pauseOnHover: false
  });
});
```

Some conflicts could be the Facebook Page Plugin (removed all code - did nothing) or Google Maps (not even on the same page of the site). No errors in dev tools console, nothing showing in sources debugging.

EDIT: I've discovered that it's running in the background but the images on the screen don't change. When I check the code in the Chrome Dev Tools, the active image is changing. It seems to be using the correct timing as per the settings too, but it's just stuck on the initial image in the actual site window.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and I haven't figured it out yet. If I find anything I will post it here.

Comment: I never figured out how to fix that. I found an old backup copy of the site and just used that instead. I gave up on trying to make the slider scroll vertically. My client didn't mind.

Comment: Turns out my problem was that I wasn't loading the css and so the animation wouldn't happen.